# Monitor a class change through version control with an IDE

Tags: eclipse, svn, intellij-idea, ide, version

Is there a way, in Intellij or Eclipse or anything else, to monitor and alert when a particular class was changed after a version control update ?

I work in a 20-people team, with 2 other teams modifying the code, with dozens of commits a day, and I would love to see when people make a change on something I'm interested in and worked on.

Edit:
To give more context, we are responsible for functionalities we implement and communication cannot be in total free-flow (some committers are in completely separate departments and floors, and don't know me or that what they change could have an impact on what I did), so I have no idea when someone tried to modify something I worked on. Sometimes, "they", fix bugs I produced that I couldn't foresee, without realising there could be more to it and that I should either broaden their fix to other parts of the code or that there is a design flaw somewhere.

The project is very big by my standard (9000 classes, 15 years old, 14000 unit/integration tests that run for 3 hours) and I'd love to find ways to fix little issues we have simply without forcing big changes yet in our processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not *within* the IDE, but in Windows you can use [CommitMonitor](http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/CommitMonitor.html) or the [Project Monitor feature in TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-projectmonitor.html) to alert you to changes in the repository.

If you are only interested in a few files, you can specify individual files or directories in the "URL to monitor" field in CommitMonitor, meeting your requirement for monitoring a handful of classes in a huge project.

Comment: Thanks I looked into both and they seem to alert you when new commits appear globally. I already monitor easily when new commits appear in intellij, but imagine out of 30 commits changing 300 classes today, I'd like to know if 5 classes I'm half responsible for have changed ? I'm not sure these tools would help but I'll try to be sure !

Comment: I just tested in CommitMonitor; you can specify individual files in the "URL to monitor" field.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Version Control window in IntelliJ for this purpose.

Here is a file I'm working on and want to see if there are any incoming changes. So I open the `Incoming` tab and press the little `Reload` icon:

[image]

And I will have lots of information about what has been changed and I have several options to show differences or update the project:

[image]

You can have this reloading in the background by changing the settings:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the very detail explanation, it would do what I want but the project has 9000 classes and I change a lot and I'd like to have an alert during the day when changes are detected on one of them I registered somehow to monitor. Since we have 30 commits a day approximately, and I can't remember all the classes I've changed myself, I'd like something less manual than going to the classes one by one and then checking changes. Do you see what I mean ?